# libcurl, how to use in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, libcurl

I've installed `libcurl` on my mac and would need to implement it into my program in order to upload files to an FTP server. I have never used external frameworks and am pretty much a newbie with Cocoa/Objective-C. Could please somebody point me to a good tutorial or tell me how to get startet with this library in myproject? I wasn't even able to find how to implement it into my project.

Comment: It's just a matter of `configure; make; sudo make install` then you can just link your executable against `libcurl.dylib`.

Comment: thanks for your answer! i have installed libcurl through macports, and have the file libcurl.dylib in opt/local/lib . is this file enough? i've read that i have to copy it into the project, else it wont work on other pc's. is there a easy to follow tutorial somewhere? ive been searching for a while but without any success.

Comment: Dylibs are dynamic libraries, so the libcurl.dylib file must be present on the target computer as well. But you don't achieve that by copying it to the project. I don't know abut a tutorial.

Comment: thanks for the additional informations! will keep googeling and post back when i am a bit more up to date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thing first, libcurl is installed by default as dynamic libraries (dylib) on your OS X so there's no need to explicitly download it using macports, etc UNLESS you want the latest version of libcurl. For example, on my OS X 10.8.2, libcurl.3.dylib, libcurl.4.dylib, and libcurl.dylib are installed by default.

To use the functions in libcurl in your program, you need to tell Xcode else Xcode will flag libcurl functions in your app as undefined.

In your Xcode project, click on Project, then Target, and then Build Phases where you'll see "Link Binary with Libraries". Click on the + symbol and enter libcurl in the search. You should see something like
[image]

Click Add to add the libcurl you want.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind answer! beeing it preinstalled on every system, will it work also on every system or do i have to add it to the project/framework library because it is dynamic? thanks!

Comment: The reason you're adding the libcurl dylib as a target build link is so that the libcurl function(s) you use in your program can be resolved to the actual libcurl dynamic library in your Mac. As for your question as to whether it'll run, it should run on current OS X as libcurl is installed by default.

Comment: thank you very much! last thing if i don't ask too much, do you know a good tutorial for this library? i've been seraching since you posted your first post but cant seem to find something that is at my skill level and not for expert programmers. thank you again for your precious help! i am sure that many in my situation will appreciate this!